# "object file" error while running the .spec.ts file in Angular9

Tags: angular, unit-testing, components, karma-jasmine

Getting the error "test is expecting test-file.pdf but it is coming as [object file]".[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3mvf.png)

Comment: There is an assertion of the following `expect(xyz).toBe('test-file.pdf')` in the test `should detect file input change and set uploadedFile model` and this is wrong. `console.log(xyz)` right before this assertion/expect to see what its value is (I bet it is an object).,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: it('should detect file input change and set uploadedFile  model', () => {
    const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer()
    dataTransfer.items.add(new File([''], 'test-file.pdf'))

    const inputDebugEl  = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[type=file]'));
    inputDebugEl.nativeElement.files = dataTransfer.files;

    inputDebugEl.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new InputEvent('change'));

    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component.uploadedFile).toBeTruthy()
    expect(component.uploadedFile).toBe('test-file.pdf')
    
});

Comment: .ts file:    export class UploadComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  uploadedFile : any

  onFileSelected() {
    const inputNode: any = document.querySelector('#file');
    this.uploadedFile  = inputNode.files[0];
    
  }
}